Flutter で作成した Windows アプリで API リクエストすると 407 エラーになってしまう
FlutterにてWindowsアプリを実装しようと考えています。
そこでAPIを作成しリクエスト送信するが407エラーになる。
なお、Webアプリ実装ですとリクエストの送信が成功します。

具体的なコードや使用している API (WebAPI?) についての説明があった方が回答が付きやすいと思います。質問は後からでも編集できるので、詳しい情報を追記してみてください。

該当のステータスコードで検索するとこんな記事が見つかるので、APIリクエストが失敗しているのではなく、インターネットへの送信をするための前段階であるイントラネット内でのProxyサーバーへの認証が出来ていないのでは？ 407エラー（Proxy Authentication Required）とは？意味をわかりやすく解説, 「HTTP 407 Proxy Authentication Required」エラーの解決方法

kunifさん　まさにイントラネット内でのProxyサーバー認証にてつまづいている状況です
